# Why is the div positioning changing on popup button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a single HTML page which has several div class. In second div class I have a registration form. When I click on submit button and check validation and give pop up, after clicking on the pop up it redirect on home div, and I want the registration div class to stay the same after clicking on the pop up button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using href to get click and call js method. You have to prevent default behavior. It may solve your prob even you don't use href.

```
function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
// your code.

 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the href value for your link is #

You could add

```
return false;
```

as the last line of the function bound to the click event